# Swift Opening/Closing App Causes ViewController to Appear More Than Once

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am having an issues where when I "close and open" an app, the same ViewController appears twice. The app is set up in such a way where when the user "closes and opens" the app, it will take them to a "PIN" ViewController where they input their PIN code. The problem is that when the user gets to the "PIN" ViewController, the ViewController shows up twice. How do I make it so that this condition doesn't occur? In addition, once the user enters the "PIN", how do I make it so that the user can go back to the page they were last one before "closing and then opening" the app?

Code in the App Delete to allow user to go to the "PIN" ViewController  when they "open and close" the app:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            print("This is run on the background queue")


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")

                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let yourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PINViewController") as! PINViewController

                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = yourVC
                appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You should remove both of

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async
DispatchQueue.main.async
```

as code is inside main thread by default

2- Code inside

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
```

will be called for example when you press home button and re-open the app again , and this isn't app close it's the app running in background

3- Use `UINavigationController` to set back VC to return to it

```
let nav = ////
nav.viewControllers = [vc1,vc2]
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
```

so vc2 will show and with back you can return to vc1

Comment: thanks-I took out the DispatchQues; does taking this out solve the ViewController showing up twice?   for 3, how do I use that to go back to the ViewController that I was on originally??

Comment: the queue was a tip it has no relation to the problem , you should make the rootVC a navigation and use pushVC of the navigation instead of changing the root of the window , also the vc will be shown every time the app goes form background to foreground according to your current code , so you may handle it with a bool value check

Comment: @Sh_Khan I've noticed that this is a thing at the moment - poor answers tell people to wrap UI stuff in `DispatchQueue.main.async` for no reason, and this gets passed on, until we end up with code like in this question. It's like a virus!

Comment: @AshleyMills i think so , plus some beginners miss understand the queue purpose so they copy,paste code